# Workbox loading wrong dynamic import url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am using workbox & babel dynamic imports for a laravel/vuejs application. I am also using `laravel-mix` and `laravel-mix-workbox` plugin to compile and generate service worker via `generateSW()`.

The assets are are loaded correctly in the root url `https://myapp.test/` based on conditions set in vue-router. like so: `https://myapp.test/assets/js/chunk1.js`.
When I visit child pages like `https://myapp.test/post/post1`, the chunks relating to the page are loaded correctly also. So far so good!

But when I visit a post page **directly** (`https://myapp.test/post/post1`), the dynamic asset urls are appended to the latest slash, meaning `https://myapp.test/post/assets/js/chunk1.js` and fails to load them.
As if the root url is set as the first page we visit.

I have tried adding `output.path` & `output.publicPath` in webpack config, but they did not help.

Related packages:

```
"devDependencies" {
   "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.2",
   "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
   "laravel-mix": "^5.0.9",
   "laravel-mix-workbox": "^0.1.4",
}
```

generateSW config:

```
mix.generateSW({
    mode: 'development',
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: /\.(?:jpg|jpeg|svg|png|json)$/,
            handler: 'CacheFirst',
        },
        {
            urlPattern: /api($|\/?.*)/,
            handler: 'NetworkFirst'
        }
    ],
    exclude: [
        /(backend.css|backend.js)/
    ],
    include: [
        /\.(?:ttf|js|css|glb)$/,
        /(\/font.png)/
    ],
    skipWaiting: true,
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by adding a [`<base>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to my html `<head>`. Turns out this is where workbox determines base URL.

```
<base href="https:://myapp.test/">
```

Any in my case in Laravel:

```
<base href="{{config('app.url')}}">
```